# Criar Campo "Numeric" do Postgres no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Preciso criar um campo do tipo **numeric** existente no postgres usando as `migrations` do laravel, alguém sabe me dizer como faço?

Tentei isso, mas não rodou:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('complementos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->numeric('comprimento');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Preciso armazenar valores tipo **50.00**, com as casas decimais assim certinho guardando os zeros depois do ponto. Caso realmente não seja possível criar o **numeric**, que outro tipo eu poderia usar?

**Erro ao rodar o migrate:**

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>
> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::numeric ()

Comment: Como vc passou o 'comprimento'?

Comment: eu passo exatamente assim: 50.00. porém o tipo float e real simplesmente não consideram o .00, e armazena so o 50.

Comment: Tente assim `$table->numeric('15,2');`

Comment: isso no "Schema::create"? E como defino o nome do campo?

Comment: Exato, vc precisa passar o tamanho e escala

Comment: postgres não tem innodb é tudo um engine só.

Comment: ok coloquei como falou, mas retorna o msm erro.

Comment: Qual é mensagem do erro?

Comment: coloquei na pergunta @rray

Comment: Cara, numeric() não existe, tente bigInteger()

Comment: mas caso  o bigInteger  não aceita 50.00, ele da erro por causa do ponto @RaphaelCaldas

Comment: você não coloca valor, ele ja tem um valor e 8bytes se não me engano, você usa: $table->bigInteger('NOME');

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso e foi criado tudo direitinho, o problema é que não consigo armazenar dados que contenham pontuação nele.

Comment: Me diz o erro que dá, pra eu entender melhor

Comment: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "50.00"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38401/discussion-between-raphael-caldas-and-raylan-soares).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já resolvido no chat, mas quem vier de fora aqui está a forma:

$table->decimal('CAMPO', 5, 2);

Comment: o "decimal" definido no laravel, justamente cria o campo do tipo "numeric" no postgres